# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
import openpyxl

# workbook object is created
workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("Book1.xlsx")
sheet_obj1 = workbook1["123"]

y =int(0)  
z = int(1.8)

for i in range(1, sheet_obj1.max_row):
    #Data From Cell For Sheet1
    D=sheet_obj1.cell(row = i+1, column = 3)

    if (y<=D.value<=z):
          print("Warning Between Row and Row")
```

i am getting this error TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' for the if statement. how can i solve this?

Comment: try to cast D.value into a number. It looks to be a string

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: `int(0)` can just be written `0`; and `int(1.8)` can just be written `1`.

Comment: @Sid negative sign  numerical values in column 3

Comment: @khelwood still doesnot work

Comment: @SadafShah I didn't say that would fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume when it read the xlsx, it could be treated as string, comparing between string and two integers would not be possible, try the following instead.

```
if (y <= int(D.value) <= z):
      print("Warning Between Row and Row")
```

If it still throw an error, it will depends on the content in the xlsx, try converting it to either int or float then the comparsion statement will work.

Besides, there is no need to cast 0 and 1.8 using int, the following code will do the job.

```
y = 0 
z = 1.8
```

Comment: @ jonath chow      if (y<=int(D)<=z):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '=-10*(($J$1-A2)/(10*$J$2))

Comment: @SadafShah I think excel has a feature where you can export your data as `.csv`. I think that way you wouldn't have to deal with excel equations.

Comment: @RoyCohen  how can i do that?

Comment: @SadafShah here are some possible ways https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/

Comment: @SadafShah https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba